# VB.NET Searching for string and copying it to clipboard

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know how to search for two strings, select everything in between them and then copy it to the clipboard.

```
    Dim str As String
    str = strcode
    If str.Contains(".m3u8") = True Then
        MsgBox("The string Contains() '.M3U8' ")
    Else
        MsgBox("The String does not Contains() '.M3U8'")
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be of some help, I have also linked to a note below that goes into further detail.

```
sub Container()
            If str.Contains(".m3u8") = True Then
                'Copy the information to the clipboard
                Clipboard.SetText(strcode)
            End If
        End Sub
```

http://www.brangle.com/wordpress/2009/08/how-to-cutcopypaste-text-into-clipboard-using-vb-net/

Answer (score 0):

Using this function:

```
Function FindText(ByVal source As String, ByVal start As String, ByVal stop As String)
    Dim startIndex As Integer = source.IndexOf(start) 
    If startIndex = -1 Then Throw New ArgumentException("start value not found in string")
    startIndex += start.Length

    Dim stopIndex As Integer = source.IndexOf(stop, startIndex)
    If stopIndex = -1 Then Throw New ArgumentException("stop value not found in string")

    Return source.SubString(startIndex, stopIndex - startIndex)
End Function
```

And call [`ClipBoard.SetText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.settext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the result.

Comment: Made the code work without an error, but I have no idea how it works